# Way to check repeated messages within a string?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, string-matching

***The messages are exact dont need to worry about variation or simbols in between, right now I am just looking for a efficient way that can check messages like the below.***

I have a message like:

```
string msg = "This is a small message !";
```

And I would like to check if that message was sent repeated times in the same string like this:

```
string msg = "This is a small message !This is a small message !";
```

or:

```
string msg = "This is a small message !This is a small message !This is a small message !";
```

or:

```
string msg = "This is a small message !This is a small message !This is a small message !This is a small message !This is a small message !";
```

I have a `LinkedList<string>` that stores the last 3 messages received and along with those last 3 message I would like to match the current messages to see if it is either equal to one of the current store messages or a repetition of any.

```
foreach (string item in myListOfMessages)
{
    if (string.Equals(msg, item))
    {
        // the message matchs one of the stored messages
    }
    else if (msg.Lenght == (item.Lenght * 2) && string.Equals(msg, string.Concat(item, "", item)))
    {
        // the message is a repetition, and ofc only works when some one sends the message twice in the same string
    }
}
```

Like I showed in the examples, the repetition could be quite large, also I am not sure if the method I presented above is the best one for what I need. It was the first idea that came to my mind but soon after I realised that it would produce a lot more work that way.

Comment: Are you asking if the method above is the 'best' method?

Comment: @Polity no I am not asking if it is the best method because I already replied that myself in the question. `Way to check repeated messages within a string?` that is the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linq to the rescue:

```
string msg = "This is a small message !";
string otherMsg = "This is a small message !This is a small message !This is a small message !This is a small message !This is a small message !";

bool isRepeated = Enumerable.Range(0, otherMsg.Length / msg.Length)
                            .Select(i => otherMsg.Substring(i *  msg.Length,  msg.Length))
                            .All( x => x == msg);
```

This approach basically takes a sub string of the length of the first message and compares each chunk with the original message.

Wrapped in a method with some pre-checking:

```
public bool IsRepeated(string msg, string otherMsg)
{
    if (otherMsg.Length < msg.Length || otherMsg.Length % msg.Length != 0)
        return false;

    bool isRepeated = Enumerable.Range(0, otherMsg.Length / msg.Length)
                                .Select(i => otherMsg.Substring(i * msg.Length, msg.Length))
                                .All(x => x == msg);
    return isRepeated;
}
```

**Edit:**

Above approach will generate unnecessary strings that will have to be gc'ed - a much more efficient and faster solution:

```
public bool IsRepeated(string msg, string otherMsg)
{
    if (otherMsg.Length < msg.Length || otherMsg.Length % msg.Length != 0)
        return false;

    for (int i = 0; i < otherMsg.Length; i++)
    {
        if (otherMsg[i] != msg[i % msg.Length])
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: That works quite well I was thinking of using the % but was not sure it would work out well.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using a Regular Expression

```
string msg = "This is a small message !";
string Input = "This is a small message !This is a small message !";

System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex r = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(msg);
System.Text.RegularExpressions.MatchCollection Matches = r.Matches(Input);

int Count = Matches.Count; //Count = 2
```

Comment: Beware that this will count all occurrances of `msg` in `Input`, even if there is new stuff in between. This is not what you want if I am understanding your problem correctly.

Comment: Good point nw. that is not what I am looking for as I need an exact match

Comment: @nw Good Point, didnt consider that!

Answer (score 1):

```
private int countRepeats(string msg, string item)
{
   if(string.Replace(msg, item).Length > 0)
      return 0;

   return msg.Length / item.Length;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string msg = "This is a small message !This is a small message !This is a small message !";
            string substring = "This is a small message !";

            string[] split = msg.Split(new string[] { substring }, StringSplitOptions.None);

            Console.WriteLine(split.Length - 1);

            foreach (string splitPart in split)
            {
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(splitPart))
                    Console.WriteLine("Extra info");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Wouldn't that fail in the same way the regex does ?

Comment: ah, true. Didn't see that answer and its comments.

Comment: Well, if the original message contains nothing extra, the split array contains only null strings. If any element of the split array is not null, you know there was some extraneous characters in the original message

Comment: @xbonez: +1 I really like this idea - you can make it much better by using `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries`: `bool isRepeated = otherMsg.Split(new string[] { msg }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Length == 0;`